# File hycolor.sty not found

Tags: hyperref, packages, miktex

Update: The error has been fixed. Update your miktex installation (hycolor) to fix the problem.

Old:

After updating my miktex installation (windows) today, i can't compile any document containing the package hyperref.
I always get the error:
"File `hycolor.sty' not found. \RequirePackage"
I tried reinstalling hyperref and hycolor in the miktex package manager.
There aren't any updates available either.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Output Log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.1.30)  30 JAN 2020 10:33
entering extended mode
**./mwe.tex
(mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3

(C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrreprt.cl
s
Document Class: scrreprt 2019/12/23 v3.28 KOMA-Script document class (report)

(C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrkbase.st
y
Package: scrkbase 2019/12/23 v3.28 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)

(C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrbase.sty
Package: scrbase 2019/12/23 v3.28 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrlfile.st
y
Package: scrlfile 2019/12/23 v3.28 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
)))
(C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\tocbasic.st
y
Package: tocbasic 2019/12/23 v3.28 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip41
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box27
)
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `toc'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `toc' on input line 137.
Class scrreprt Info: File `scrsize11pt.clo' used instead of
(scrreprt)           file `scrsize11.clo' to setup font sizes on input line 242
0.

(C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrsize11pt
.clo
File: scrsize11pt.clo 2019/12/23 v3.28 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt
)
)
(C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\typearea.st
y
Package: typearea 2019/12/23 v3.28 KOMA-Script package (type area)
\ta@bcor=\skip42
\ta@div=\count80
\ta@hblk=\skip43
\ta@vblk=\skip44
\ta@temp=\skip45
\footheight=\skip46
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 10
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 418.25555pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 17.3562pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = 17.3562pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 595.80026pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -25.16531pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.6pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
(typearea)              on input line 1718.
)
\c@part=\count81
\c@chapter=\count82
\c@section=\count83
\c@subsection=\count84
\c@subsubsection=\count85
\c@paragraph=\count86
\c@subparagraph=\count87
\scr@dte@chapter@maxnumwidth=\skip47
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\chapter on input line 5546.
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip48
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\section on input line 5556.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\section on input line 5556.
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip49
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=true'
(scrreprt)           for `\part on input line 5565.
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip50
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subsection on input line 5575.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subsection on input line 5575.
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip51
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subsubsection on input line 5585.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subsubsection on input line 5585.
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip52
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\paragraph on input line 5595.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\paragraph on input line 5595.
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip53
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subparagraph on input line 5605.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subparagraph on input line 5605.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip54
\belowcaptionskip=\skip55
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box28
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lof'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lof' on input line 6841.
\scr@dte@figure@maxnumwidth=\skip56
\c@figure=\count88
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lot'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lot' on input line 6858.
\scr@dte@table@maxnumwidth=\skip57
\c@table=\count89
Class scrreprt Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 7027.
\bibindent=\dimen102
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks15
\inpenc@posthook=\toks16
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\t1enc.def"
File: t1enc.def 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty"
Package: hyperref 2020/01/14 v7.00d Hypertext links for LaTeX

(C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2019/12/15 v1.24 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2019/11/07 v1.0c TeX engine tests
)
(C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.s
ty
Package: pdftexcmds 2019/11/24 v0.31 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.s
ty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.s
ty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
)
(C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\kvdefine
keys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfescape.s
ty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)

! LaTeX Error: File `hycolor.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.132 \RequirePackage
                     {letltxmacro}[2008/06/13]
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3470 strings out of 492448
 70556 string characters out of 3129714
 276102 words of memory out of 3000000
 7861 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 4709 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 43i,1n,72p,10100b,246s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: I have just done an update and I obtain the same error "File hycolor.sty not found" ... There is only a .tpm

Comment: After updating my miktex installation (windows) today, i can't also compile. I get the error: "File `hycolor.sty' not found.

Comment: @HoudaFriaa Use the workaround from Ulrike Fischer's answer until miktex gets another update.

Comment: You need to open MiKTeX Console and search for hycolor in the packages section. Install it and it should work again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is a packaging error in miktex. That happens sometimes. In such cases go to

https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues

and report the issue (if it hasn't been done yet by someone else).

I added an issue: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/159

As a work-around until miktex corrects this: Get `hycolor.dtx` from ctan
https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hycolor, run

tex hycolor.dtx

This will unpack the style and you can copy it to your current working folder.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: After a tex hycolor.dtx ... Where do I copy the files in C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9 ?

Comment: @AlBundy put them in your document folder and delete them again tomorrow or whenever miktex updates (normally this is fast).

Comment: It does not work ... 

Enter file name: **C:\Users\Owner\Documents\hycolor\hycolor.sty**
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> C:\Users 
                    \Owner \Documents \hycolor \hycolor 
l.132 \RequirePackage
                     {letltxmacro}[2008/06/13]
?

Comment: Are you sure that you correctly unpacked the hycolor.sty? Open it in your editor. How do the first two lines look like?

Comment: I can confirm the workaround works, be careful to download hycolor.dtx and not copy-paste its contents. "tex hycolor.dtx" wouldnt work if i created a new file, I suspect encodings...

Comment: I have just updated hyperref and hycolor but still not work for me (same messages). I think they have missed hycolor.sty ....

Comment: @AlBundy yes the miktex package is broken. You will have to install hycolor.sty **manually** if you want to use it. Or wait until tomorrow.